# Restyle Resque web interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra, resque

I am starting using Redis for our web application, but I planning integrate its web admin interface to our application, at least in styling (partially this application will be an administration interface of our infrastructure). Is there a way to inject some js/css to this application?

I know Redis uses Sinatra, but I does not know very well that framework, so possibly I cannot found some trivial solution. If this happen, pls. help me with a link to some description/tutorial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a stylesheet (`lib/resque/server/public/style.css`) that you can edit to change the appearance of the Resque web interface. You should fetch the [source code from github](http://github.com/defunkt/resque), make your changes and run your modified resque application.